# Как отсортировать текстовый список файлов по расширению?

Tags: linux, bash

Есть файл log.txt. В этом **файле** содержится громадный список файлов и расширений, где каждое новое название начинается с новой строчки, приблизительно вот так:

```
1.jpg
common.pdf
script.sh
Justin Bieber - Baby.mp3
```

Нужно перекинуть весь список в еще один файл, в котором список файлов будет упорядочен по **расширению**.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

можно, например, воспользоваться программой *sort*, передав ей две опции:

- указание использовать в качестве разделителя полей точку: `-t.`
- указание сортировать по второму полю: `-k 2`

```
$ sort -t. -k 2 исходный-файл > отсортированный-файл
```

---

уточнения: так называемые [«расширения» файла](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8_%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0) пришли к нам из файловой системы *fat16* (а в неё — из файловой системы для [операционной системы cp/m](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/CP/M)), где это были отдельные сущности. с тех пор данное понятие присутствует лишь по традиции и довольно условно.

в операционных системах же системах *unix* и их «наследниках» (*bsd*, *gnu* и т.п.) этого понятия не существовало изначально: имя файла, например, `file.tar.gz`, — это **цельная** сущность, в ней нет никаких «расширений». да, строку `.tar.gz` можно считать «суффиксом» в имени файла. или даже двумя суффиксами: `tar` и `gz`.

потому мой ответ и содержит предложение выделить в имени файла первую точку, подразумевая, что после неё и находится *суффикс имени файла*, или, в традиционно-устаревшей терминологии — «расширение».

---

если же всё-таки требуется сортировка по самому последнему суффиксу в имени файла, т.е., чтобы файл с именем `a.z.a` был раньше файла с именем `a.b`, то можно, например, воспользоваться такой конструкцией (она будет корректно работать при наличии **любых** символов в исходном файле, и вертикальной черты, и символа табуляции):

```
$ rev исходный-файл | sed -r 's/^([^.]+).*/&\t\1/' | rev | sort | cut -f 2- > отсортированный-файл
```

Comment: Но в этом случае в названии файлов не может быть еще одной точки.

Comment: По второму полю не получится, если в имени файла больше одной точки.

Comment: @SlavaSemushin, запросто. сколько угодно. первая из точек и служит для выделения **суффикса** внутри имени файла.

Comment: @PinkTux, первая из точек — это и есть разделитель внутри имени файла. например, имя файла: `a.b.c`. суффиксом в этом случае будет `.b.c`.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, `ls -X` с этим не согласен, например.

Comment: @PinkTux, я дополнил ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Можно ввести временное поле с расширением файла, отсортировать по нему, а затем удалить это поле. Пример:

```
$ while read F; do printf '%s|%s\n' "$(echo "$F" | sed 's|.*\.\([a-zA-Z0-9]\+\)$|\1|')" "$F"; done<test.txt | sort -t'|' -k1 | cut -d'|' -f2-
1.jpg
2.jpg
Justin Bieber - Baby.mp3
common.pdf
script.sh
```

Comment: будет ли сортировка работать корректно при наличии в файле символов `|`?

Comment: @alexander-barakin не проверял, но должно. Вдобавок такие файлы редкость и чтобы их создать нужно постараться :)

Comment: создать файл — элементарно: `touch file\|`. но речь в вопросе была о **содержимом** файла. команда `echo 'a|b' | while read F; do printf '%s|%s\n' "$(echo "$F" | sed 's|.*\.\([a-zA-Z0-9]\+\)$|\1|')" "$F"; done | sort -t'|' -k1 | cut -d'|' -f2-` возвращает: `b|a|b`, т.е., строка «портится».

Comment: @alexander-barakin в вашем примере `a|b` не имеет расширения, оттого и результат такой.

Comment: строка в файле не обязательно должна содержать символ `.`, но вполне может содержать символ `|`. и даже имя файла не обязательно должно содержать символ `.`, но вполне может содержать символ `|`. но даже если строка содержит точку: `echo 'a.b|c' | while read F; do printf '%s|%s\n' "$(echo "$F" | sed 's|.*\.\([a-zA-Z0-9]\+\)$|\1|')" "$F"; done | sort -t'|' -k1 | cut -d'|' -f2-`, то получается: `c|a.b|c`

Answer (score 0):

Можно вытащить расширение с помощью awk (переменная `$NF` хранит последнее поле - т.е. расширение), прилепить его к началу каждой строки, отсортировать нормальным образом и затем удалить лишнее из начала строки:

```
awk -F. '{ printf "%s\t%s\n", $NF, $0 }' file | sort | cut -f2-
```

Comment: будет ли сортировка работать корректно при наличии в файле символов табуляции?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin странно, но работает (думал, что если таб в расширении будет, то сломается).

Comment: `echo -e 'a\tb' | awk -F. '{ printf "%s\t%s\n", $NF, $0 }' | sort | cut -f2- | hexdump -C` возвращает: `00000000  62 09 61 09 62 0a |b.a.b.|`, т.е., строка «портится».